# How do I implement rowspan in HTML table that is rendered from a pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, html, pandas

I have a table with multiple columns which are hierarchical in nature. I would like to render the DataFrame with rowspans so that the HTML output looks nice. I am also applying styling to the dataframe so i need to use `df.style().render()`

This is what the code results in

[image: This is what the code results in]

This is what I need to have

[image: This is what I need to have]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas [`df.to_html()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html) should account for colspan and rowspan as needed if you have a [`multiindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html) set up. Given the following dataframe,

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    ('A1', 'B1', '1', 'extra'), ('A1', 'B1', '2', 'extra'),
    ('A1', 'B2', '3', 'extra'), ('A1', 'B2', '4', 'extra'),
    ('A2', 'B1', '5', 'extra'), ('A2', 'B1', '6', 'extra'),
    ('A2', 'B2', '7', 'extra'), ('A2', 'B2', '8', 'extra'),
    ], columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
```

You can set the columns you want as your index:

```
df.set_index(['A', 'B', 'C'], inplace=True)

df
#              D
# A  B  C
# A1 B1 1  extra
#       2  extra
#    B2 3  extra
#       4  extra
# A2 B1 5  extra
#       6  extra
#    B2 7  extra
#       8  extra
```

Then to view it as html, you just call `df.to_html()`. You can pass in a file name such as `df.to_html("output.html")` which yields:

```html
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th>D</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>A</th>
      <th>B</th>
      <th>C</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="4" valign="top">A1</th>
      <th rowspan="2" valign="top">B1</th>
      <th>1</th>
      <td>extra</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2</th>
      <td>extra</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2" valign="top">B2</th>
      <th>3</th>
      <td>extra</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>4</th>
      <td>extra</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="4" valign="top">A2</th>
      <th rowspan="2" valign="top">B1</th>
      <th>5</th>
      <td>extra</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>6</th>
      <td>extra</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2" valign="top">B2</th>
      <th>7</th>
      <td>extra</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>8</th>
      <td>extra</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```