# How to get rid of extra th cells when rendering multiindex pandas dataframe to html?

Tags: python, html, pandas

I am generating an HTML table from a multi-index dataframe. In the output there are some empty th cells. Is there any way to get rid of them neatly?

Implemented in a similar fashion as this question:
[How do I implement rowspan in HTML table that is rendered from a pandas Dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57812112/how-do-i-implement-rowspan-in-html-table-that-is-rendered-from-a-pandas-datafram/58211124?noredirect=1#comment102799959_58211124)

Currently using string replace to manually go through and edit the string. It results in buggy outputs.

The table is a summary of another dataframe where there is a multi-index and the columns are all groupings that come from a single column in the original dataframe.

[Table Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGrrp.jpg)

[Ideal Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3AWBd.jpg)

Current HTML Output

```html
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th>D</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>A</th>
      <th>B</th>
      <th>C</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="4" valign="top">A1</th>
      <th rowspan="2" valign="top">B1</th>
      <th>1</th>
      <td>extra</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2</th>
      <td>extra</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2" valign="top">B2</th>
      <th>3</th>
      <td>extra</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>4</th>
      <td>extra</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="4" valign="top">A2</th>
      <th rowspan="2" valign="top">B1</th>
      <th>5</th>
      <td>extra</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>6</th>
      <td>extra</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2" valign="top">B2</th>
      <th>7</th>
      <td>extra</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>8</th>
      <td>extra</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: could you give the structure of the dataframe.

Comment: Its sensitive information. But if you look at the link above the data frame is similar to that. Basically 5 level multi-index along with 4 columns.

Comment: Added picture and description.